# Why is output of the following program how r u?

Tags: c, if-statement

The following code is the basic implementation of the `if - else` conditional statements -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int x;
int main() 
{
    if(x)
        printf("hi");
    else
        printf("how r u \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Global scope vars are initialized to 0, ie. false.  If 'x' had been declared inside main(), it would have been UB.

Answer (score 4):

> **6.9.2 External object definitions**
>
> **Semantics**
>
> **1** If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and an initializer, the
>   declaration is an external definition for the identifier.
>
> **2** A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
>   without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a
>   tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
>   identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
>   the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
>   equal to 0.

---

So, Global variables are never left uninitialized, they are always initialized to `0`. Hence the output `how r u`.

Comment: `x` is a global variable, static storage. It's guaranteed to be initialized to 0

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, my bad. I missed that.

Comment: Honest mistake :) I've included the relevant sections of the C standard in my answer meanwhile

Answer (score 3):

According to the C standard, your code does not trigger undefined behaviour:

> If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>   - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>   - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;

This is taken from the C11 standard, but C89, and C99 both defined this behaviour, too:

> If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, it is initialized implicitly as if every member that has arithmetic type were assigned 0 and every member that has pointer type were assigned a null pointer constant.

Because you're declaring `x` as a global variable, it has static storage duration, and therefore `x` is guaranteed to be initialized to `0` (it being an int, it obviously has an arithmetic type).

Your main function, therefore reads like this:

```
int main(void)//use int main(void), not int main() 
{
    if(0)//x is 0, 0 is false
        printf("hi");
    else
        printf("how r u \n");//because if (x) is false, this is executed
    return 0;
}
```

That's why the output of your program will be *"How r u"*.

Answer (score 1):

//global
int x;

You have declared 'x' as global variable ... Therefore it's default value is 0 .

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is just all shades of wrong: global variables _are_ initialized, and a stack variable does not contain values used _"by another program"_ until you initialize it

Comment: It's not garbage. Uninitialized global variables go into the BSS segment. These are initialized to zero.